# ClickOnce deployment - Deployment Exception

Tags: .net, winforms, clickonce

I'm using ClickOnce to release a deployment of a windows application. I want it to overwrite the existing application with the new release.

I have increased the Publish Version number in the publish tab and I'm using the same certificate as the previous version. The product name is also the same.

Whenever I publish I get the following error:

- An application for this deployment is already installed with a different application identity.

This seemed to work fine in Visual Studio 2010 but since upgrading to 2013 this error seems to happen. This may not be relevant but I thought I'd mention it just in case.

Comment: Did you change the version of .NET Framework when you upgraded?

Answer (score 0):

Did you change the "target cpu"? Maybe it was 32bit and you changed to "Any", for example. Since you changed the VS version, maybe it happened when it converted the project.

Comment: Initially it was 'any' so I changed it to 'x86' but still get the same issue